# E3 instance allow password login

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services

I created an E3 instance of Ubuntu 16.04.

1. ssh into user ubuntu and create new user with root privileges
2. `sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
3. change line 52 `PasswordAuthentication` from no to yes
4. try to login with ssh phil@00.000.000.0

Get error: `Permission denied (publickey).`

Also tried changing line 28, `PermitRootLogin` to yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step I missed was restarting the ssh service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh reload
```

Comment: Good that you solved it. If you can solve a problem in nine minutes, perhaps you should wait a little longer before posting a question next time.

Comment: @Tim I was working on it for a while before posting